# Adding references in PHP to an array creates an array of references

Tags: php, arrays, pointers, foreach, reference

Not sure if this is considered a bug

```
$array = ['numbers' => [1, 2, 3]];
foreach ($array as &$numbers) {
    $numbers = [4, 5, 6];
}
var_dump($array);
modify_array($array);
var_dump($array);

function modify_array($array_arg)
{
    $array_arg['numbers'] = [1, 2, 3];
}
```

Prints

```
array(1) {
  ["numbers"]=>
  &array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(4)
    [1]=>
    int(5)
    [2]=>
    int(6)
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["numbers"]=>
  &array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Notice that $array was not passed by reference to modify_array() however the nested array was modified. It sounds logical but not sure if this is documented!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using foreah with reference you prevent PHP to make a copy of array, so you are working on original array. When you finish foreach loop you should `unset()` variable used in loop, because it still remains in memory. If you don't do this, you will get unpredictable results like this one presented in your question. Even in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) you have a warning:

> **Warning** Reference of a *$value* and the last array element remain even after the *foreach* loop. It is recommended to destroy it by
>   *unset()*.

[Here](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/dmcaloon/PHP-Memory-Management-Foreach) you can find really good examples of foreach loops without unsetting.

So if you add `unset()`, everything looks as it should

```
$array = ['numbers' => [1, 2, 3]];
foreach ($array as &$numbers) {
    $numbers = [4, 5, 6];
}
unset($numbers);
var_dump($array);
modify_array($array);
var_dump($array);

function modify_array($array_arg) {
    $array_arg['numbers'] = [1, 2, 3];
}
```

Result:

```
array(1) { ["numbers"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(4) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(6) } } 
array(1) { ["numbers"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(4) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(6) } }
```

Comment: Just want to say that if anyone wants confirmation: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hcpoWB Only thing I added was the line with br tag.

Comment: "If you don't do this, you will get unpredictable results" --- what tells us the results must be *unpredictable*? The warning you quoted does not explain the behaviour.

Comment: I agree, the results would be very predictable according to the Warning, but this is still a useful answer besides that.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite following code:

```
foreach ($array as &$numbers) {
    $numbers = [4, 5, 6];
}
```

To smth like this:

```
  $array['numbers'] = &$array['numbers'];
  $array['numbers'] = [4,5,6];
```

It'll be easier to understand such a behavior, and this seems to be a known issue.
(See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php#87532)